# hasPrevious() Method not working

Tags: java, arrays, list, iterator

I don't understand why my hasPrevious iterator is not functioning, it looks like this:

```
public void previousSong(){
    Iterator<Song> iterator = songs.iterator();
if(iterator.hasPrevious()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.previous().toString());
}
}
```

I have another function using hasNext() and it works, but this one will not.

```
public void nextSong(){
    Iterator<Song> iterator = songs.iterator();
if(iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
}
}
```

I am not sure if this method is no longer in existence or not, but when I look into it, Java websites speak of it. I don't understand why it is not functioning.

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description. By "not working," do you mean "this code does not compile?" [There is no `hasPrevious()` method in the `Iterator` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). What "Java websites speak of it?"

Comment: It doesn't compile because it doesn't exist I suppose, and here is the website http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html. @MattBall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hasPrevious` and `previous` methods are only defined for ListIterators (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), a sub-interface of Iterator. As you're only using an Iterator the only defined methods are `hasNext()`, `next` and `remove` - see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html.

Comment: thank you, I was really confused as to why it was not working, I had no idea that there were two separate iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Only the `ListIterator` can walk backwards. The normal `Iterator` class can't.

So if you use `ListIterator` instead of `Iterator` it will work :)

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea they were different and that two existed.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
       public void previousSong(){
        ListIterator<Song> it = songs.listIterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next().toString());
    }

   // and now you can use hasprevious()

      while(it.hasPrevious()) {
            System.out.println(it.previous().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create an array list

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();   

  // add elements to the array list
      list.add("C++");
      list.add("Java");
      list.add("Php");
      list.add("Python");
      list.add("Ruby");
      list.add("Perl");

     //Create the object of ListIterator through listIterator() method
      ListIterator object=list.listIterator();
     // Modify the list element 
      while(object.hasNext()) {
          String language=(String) object.next() ;
          object.set(language+"+");
      }
     // Show element in pervious order
      while(object.hasPrevious()) {
          System.out.println(object.previous());
      }
```

It should work by first implementing in forward direction then in backward direction.

Answer (score 0):

don't use Iterator in this Interface hasPrevious() function is not defined 
use ListIterator

```
    ListIterator lt =al.listIterator(al.size());
    while(lt.hasPrevious())
    {
        System.out.println(lt.previous());
    }
```

this will take into the last location of the collection object